# Mondrian Olap drilldown algorithm

Tags: java, olap, mondrian, drilldown

I didn't found but may be someone could me explain - OLAP cube is a combination of all possible aggregation, so related to Mondrian - leaf level is data in fact table or it is a minimum aggregate (cell) ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Level are attributes (characteristics of the cells aggregated measures) of dimension tables. Each dimension table is a dimension in the data cube.
So to perform an OLAP operation drill-down, you should increase the granularity of the view. While the roll-up the reverse.

Assuming you have a consumer dimension. In this dimension you have the following attributes: region, country and city. A drill-down operation is view a nation and you then view the cities of this nation. How does the Mondrian, for example.
The roll-up operation is the reverse, as you view the nations, you do a roll-up and see the parents of that nation. That is, the drill-down do levels down the hierarchy, while the roll-up rises.

These data are seen always in accordance with an aggregate measure, which in this case could be a recipe for profit. So you could see the recipe for the nation, and then navigate the hierarchy of cities and seeing the country, making a drill-down and roll up.

Access [BJIn OLAP](http://gbd.dc.ufscar.br/bjinolap/index.html). It performs these OLAP operations and contains examples of them.[1](http://gbd.dc.ufscar.br/bjinolap/index.html)

I hope this helps.